# Why does the PowerShell -and operator require parentheses around function arguments?

Tags: powershell, syntax

My team ran into a logic error when using the PowerShell `-and` operator. The operator produces an incorrect result when the left-hand side argument is a function *and* it is not wrapped in parenthesis:

```
function TrueFunction
{
  return $true
}

Write-Host "Zero:  " (TrueFunction)
Write-Host "One:   " (-not (TrueFunction))
Write-Host "Two:   " (!(TrueFunction))
Write-Host "Three: " ((-not (TrueFunction)))
Write-Host "Four:  " ((TrueFunction) -and (-not (TrueFunction)))
Write-Host "Five:  " (TrueFunction -and (-not (TrueFunction)))
Write-Host "Six:   " ($true -and (-not (TrueFunction)))
```

The expected output is:

```
Zero:   True
One:    False
Two:    False
Three:  False
Four:   False
Five:   False
Six:    False
```

while the actual output is:

```
Zero:   True
One:    False
Two:    False
Three:  False
Four:   False
Five:   True  // Wrong
Six:    False
```

Why is PowerShell producing an incorrect output for case five?

I reviewed [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators?view=powershell-7.2) on PowerShell logical operators and wrote the minimal program to reproduce the issue above.

Comment: expected, `-and (-not (TrueFunction))` is seen as an argument of your function in example 5. should be `(TrueFunction) -and (-not (TrueFunction))` as shown in example 4

Comment: Change your function body to `return @($true) + $args` and run example 5 again to see what I mean

Comment: To add to Santiago's comments, and to answer the question in your post's title: It isn't the `-and` operator, specifically, that requires enclosing function calls to be enclosed in `(...)` - it is a fundamental syntax requirement in order for _commands_ (which includes function calls) to be able to participate in _expressions_ - see the linked duplicate for details.